# Python code to extract all the methods from a JAVA file

Tags: android, python

I have a file MainActivity.java

```js
public class MainActivity
  extends Activity
{
  EditText etResponse;
  TextView tvIsConnected;
  
  public static String GET(String paramString)
  {
    try
    {
      InputStream localInputStream = new DefaultHttpClient().execute(new HttpGet(paramString)).getEntity().getContent();
      if (localInputStream != null) {
        return convertInputStreamToString(localInputStream);
      }
      return "Did not work!";
    }
    catch (Exception localException)
    {
      Log.d("InputStream", localException.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
    return "";
  }
  
  private static String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream paramInputStream)
    throws IOException
  {
    BufferedReader localBufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(paramInputStream));
    String str2;
    for (String str1 = "";; str1 = str1 + str2)
    {
      str2 = localBufferedReader.readLine();
      if (str2 == null)
      {
        paramInputStream.close();
        return str1;
      }
    }
  }
  
  public boolean isConnected()
  {
    NetworkInfo localNetworkInfo = ((ConnectivityManager)getSystemService("connectivity")).getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return (localNetworkInfo != null) && (localNetworkInfo.isConnected());
  }
  
  protected void onCreate(Bundle paramBundle)
  {
    super.onCreate(paramBundle);
    setContentView(2130903040);
    this.etResponse = ((EditText)findViewById(2131165185));
    this.tvIsConnected = ((TextView)findViewById(2131165184));
    if (isConnected())
    {
      this.tvIsConnected.setBackgroundColor(-16724992);
      this.tvIsConnected.setText("You are conncted");
    }
    for (;;)
    {
      new HttpAsyncTask(null).execute(new String[] { "http://www.google.com" });
      return;
      this.tvIsConnected.setText("You are NOT conncted");
    }
  }
```

and I want to search for all the methods used in this file such as onCreate(), execute(), setText(), DefaultHttpClient() etc using Python language. 
I have tried using regular expressions but is not helping me much.

Comment: Regular expressions are not expressive enough to parse code. You'll need a BNF parser to do it properly. Now, if you rely on the code being "properly" formatted, then you can search for `(\w*\s*\w*\s*\w+\s+\w+\s*\([^\)]\))`; which are: visibility, modifier, return type, name & params.

Comment: Try  fdik.org/pyPEG/